# How to translate magento 2.3.2 frontend only

Tags: magento2.3

I would manually translate but how do i do this?

I remember at magento 1, we can find an en_US excell file at file manager and edit it as needed

how do i find this same file at magento2, and will this method works?

I'm at magento 2.3.2

Answer (score 3):

In magento 2.x, Translation file is located in `i18n` folder.

You can put translation at theme level by creating:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/i18n/en_US.csv

You can put translation at Module level by creating:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/i18n/en_US.csv

You can also put at global level by creating:

> app/i18n/en_US.csv

Comment: Thank you. Attempting at theme level by accessing public_html/app/design/frontend/magento/ but ends at {empty folder}, at module level i try accessing public_html/app/code/Vendor/Module/{but no i18n folder}, at global level public_html/app/{but no no i18n folder} is this normal? do you mean the folder mentioned normally do not exist yet and should be created by myself?

Comment: if you do not have custom theme and module, you can directly put `app/i18n/en_US.csv`. You need to create folder and file as well!

Comment: You can create folder if not available!

Comment: As per your instruction, i have create folder at public_html/app/i18n/en_US.csv, the csv file is taken from /lib/web/i18n/en_US.csv and translated. After upload new translated file, i then reindex, clean cache, flush cache, flush browser, but no change is showing.. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

you can find en_US.csv in following path

```
/lib/web/i18n/en_US.csv
```

you can edit it.

Comment: Thanks.. However i can't find the string i want to translate in this file (especially checkout related words), such as first name, last name, You can create an account after checkoutetc