# Magento2: How to translate language

Tags: magento2, language

In header.phtml I add new banner:

```
<div class="promo hide" id="promo"> <span class="closebtnpr" id="dismiss">x</span>
  <center><b><font color="red">BLACK WEEK!:</font> TYLKO TERAZ <b><font color="red">NAWET DO -63%*</font></b> NA +150 MAREK PREMIUM!</b></center>
</div>
```

But now this banner is displayed in Polish language on all stores website. How can I translate this banner for others websites stores?

Comment: first you need to put text like `<?php echo __( 'your-context'); ?>` and put translation in CSV like https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284768/how-to-translate-magento-2-3-2-frontend-only/284774#284774

Comment: Thank you. You can add answear below. After this I give you vote.

Comment: welcome :) glad to know it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in comment, You need to Add text like:

```
<?php echo __('your-context'); ?>
```

After that you need to put translation in CSV file.

For more information about How to add translation You can refer [Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284768/how-to-translate-magento-2-3-2-frontend-only/284774#284774)