# Magento 2.3.x Text Replacement through i18n/en_US.csv

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.2, magento2.3.3

Is it possible to replace the text in Product/catalog Information through i18n/en_US.csv file?

Comment: please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296685/magento2-how-to-translate-language/296689#296689

Comment: @Pawan, Product title comes from the catalog/inventory. I want to replace the product title through csv file, so it would just text replacment in csv, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: @Pawan - I am trying but it's not working through i18n csv file, do you know how it will work.