# How to translate this 4 items(s) in magento 2 in my order tab after login

Tags: magento2

[image]

How to translate this 4 items(s) in magento 2 in my order tab after login

Comment: 1st way =>
Please enable translate inline option from admin => Store => Configuration => Developer => Translate Inline => Yes and check by hovering mouse on text showing book icon, click and set the name accordingly. 2ndWay => Go to your theme and open en_us.csv and put your text there.

Comment: basically i want to know in which file this text is written  i also want to change this text

Comment: please enable path hints for admin. Magento will show you file. Store => Configuration => Developer => Template Path Option => Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below files is responsible for showing `4 items(s)` (pager)

> /vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/pager.phtml

If you want to change the text, you need to override in your theme with following path:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/pager.phtml

If you want to put translation for your custom text, Please have a look at [Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284768/how-to-translate-magento-2-3-2-frontend-only/284774#284774)

Comment: Thanks alot  it is in pager.phtml

Comment: welcome @JunaidAshfaq