# Magento 2.3.5 - Inline Translate within a CMS Block

Tags: magento2.3, cms-block, inline-translations

I'm running a multi website and store setup.
I'm trying to use inline translation within a CMS block so I don't have to create multiple blocks for different stores.

For example I'm using this within a CMS block to enable inline translation.

```
<h1 class="hero-h1"><?php echo __('Welcome to this website') ?></h1>
```

However it doesn't appear on the page, when I inspect element it shows as

```
<h1 class="hero-h1"><!--?php echo __('Welcome to this website') ?--></h1>
```

Is there anyway text can be inline translated in a CMS Block?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

php translate will not work in static block

you need to add like:

```
<h1 class="hero-h1">{{trans "Welcome to this website" }}</h1>
```

You can add translation as per [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284768/how-to-translate-magento-2-3-2-frontend-only/284774#284774)

Comment: Thanks, that worked.

Comment: welcome...... :)