# How to translate static content within CMS

Tags: magento2, translate, language-package, multi-language

I have a language pack installed and its working but it does not work for my own static content I have created within the CMS.

For example I created a page within the CMS.

```
<div>
 <p>Hello world</p>
</div>
```

How can I get that to translate?

Comment: please check : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312978/magento-2-3-5-inline-translate-within-a-cms-block/312980#312980

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translation of the CMS page requires manual creation of a new one with translated content and needs to be stored according to store view.

Check [this](https://magefan.com/blog/translate-cms-page-in-magento-2) for more details.

Comment: ohh okay simple enough Thank you