# Add translation for a plugin

Tags: plugin, i18n

The site that I am working on is using he_IL as primary language of the theme (I think).
I installed a plugin which only has en_US.csv its i18 folder

I added an he_IL.csv in the i18l folder, but I don't see that it is picked up in the UI.

I tried running these commands, and refresh the UI (ctrl-f5) but it is still not working.

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US he_IL --language en_US --language he_IL 
php bin/magento cache:clean; php bin/magento cache:flush
```

I checked, and the string that I want to replace is wrapped in `__()` inside the phtml file.

What am I missing?

Comment: try https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284768/how-to-translate-magento-2-3-2-frontend-only/284774#284774

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create some new translations with:

```
php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o     app/code/Company/Module/i18n/he_IL.csv app/code/Company/Module
```

This will create the csv file that you want, in the place it has to be and with the translation strings that you need.

If your `__()` is not in there then you will need to look at your code.

Comment: I don't know why, but the plugin i18l files didn't work. I ended up changing the text from the template i18l language file, it did work from there.

Comment: On a further check, I don't know what happened, but after running your command and changing the texts in the generated file, suddenly it worked. So I am accepting your answer. Thanks!