# How to Change "All Categories" text in Search box in Magento 2.4.1 Porto Theme

Tags: magento2.4.1, porto-theme

[image]

I'm working with Magento 2.4.1 Porto theme and want to change/translate the search box default category "All Categories". Is there any way to do this?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This text is coming from module i.e `Mageplaza`

File path:

> app/code/Mageplaza/Search/Helper/Data.php

If you want to add translation, please refer [Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284768/how-to-translate-magento-2-3-2-frontend-only/284774#284774)

Hope above will help!

Comment: Thank you for help