# Translation doesn't work on breadcrumbs added by xml in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, xml, localisation, contact-us, breadcrumbs

I am trying like below to put Breadcrumb and translation in Contact page of Magento 2. But can't translate. I put translation file under /vendor/magento/module-contact/i18n/zh_Hant_TW.csv Is it not correct?

```
    <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
                 <action method="addCrumb" translate="crumbInfo.title crumbInfo.label">
                     <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">home</argument>
                     <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                         <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
                         <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
                         <item name="link" xsi:type="string">/</item>
                     </argument>
                 </action>
                 <action method="addCrumb" translate="crumbInfo.title crumbInfo.label">
                     <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Contact Us</argument>
                     <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                         <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Contact Us</item>
                         <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Contact Us</item>
                     </argument>
                 </action>
                 
    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: plz try `<item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Contact Us</item>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `translate="true"` if you want translation for it.

like:

```
<item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Contact Us</item>
```

For translation, you can refer [Answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284768/how-to-translate-magento-2-3-2-frontend-only/284774#284774)

Hope above will help!

Comment: Yes. Now it is working when put < translate="true" >. Thanks a lot for your support. <3

Comment: welcome... @Nang