# Magento 2 modify CSV file translation not taking place

Tags: magento2, localisation

I added my translation text into the csv

```
/app/i18n/vendor/fr_ca/fr_CA.csv
```

for the Magento Review Module

```
"Write a review","Écrire une critique",module,Magento_Review
```

However, I have no idea why it didn't make any changes? I did static content deploy again, flush the cache and it not showing. Am I missing any procedure? Please help

Comment: please refer : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284768/how-to-translate-magento-2-3-2-frontend-only/284774#284774

Comment: I did add the translation into my existing CSV file. But still not showing, do you know why? anything need to compile?

Comment: could you share exact full path of CSV ?

Comment: /app/i18n/vendor/fr_ca/fr_CA.csv

Comment: wrong file path.you want to translate using theme Or module ?

Comment: the rest of my other translation is in that file too, which is working properly. May be I should modify the csv file inside the module folder?