# How to change TAX to GST in Magento 2.4?

Tags: magento2.4

I need to change all the txt "TAX" to "GST" for the entile website, what is the easy way to do it? Thank you.

Comment: You can put translated word in CSV. Please refer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284768/how-to-translate-magento-2-3-2-frontend-only/284774#284774

Answer (score 0):

Just Open *<Magento 2 Root>/vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n/en_US.csv* and find Tax. And changes like below:

```
"Estimate Tax","Estimate GST"
"Estimate Shipping and Tax","Estimate Shipping and GST"
"Excl. Tax","Excl. GST"
"Incl. Tax","Incl. GST"
```

Check this: https://prnt.sc/13l7sbx

Comment: Hi Msquare, I did get the Excl Incl Tax change to Excl Incl GST done in Checkout area. I also have changed all second Tax to GST in module-sales, module-catalog/i18n/en-US, but after flash the cache, on the product page and catalog page and ORDER SUMMARY, they still show Excl Tax, Incl Tax. Any idea to change all the Tax to GST? My website shows both Excl & Incl price at the same time. Thank you.

Comment: You need to run the upgrade and static content deploy command after run the cache clean command and you can show the result.

Comment: These two commands?  php bin/magento setup:upgrade, 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: Please checked and update me.

Comment: After running these two commands, my website is crashed.

Comment: Check how many stores and deploy every store content.